# Is there a tool where you give a list of things and it returns related words?

Tags: search-engine

Is there some kind of tool you can enter simple queries and it will use AI to process it and provide you an answer relating your query to it's possible meanings? For example:

```
relate: animal, fast, not bird -> cheetahs, lions, etc
relate: python, else if -> elif, condition blocks, programming
relate: avogadro, constant -> 6.02E23, chemistry, atom, etc
relate: current time, Javascript -> Date.now(), (new Date()).getTime(), etc
relate: [1,5,4,6,2], [1,2,4,5,6] -> sorting algorithm, bubblesort, quicksort
relate: [2,3,6,7], [5,10,37,43] -> x²+1 function
relate: cup, glass, break, sound -> ressonance frequency, waves
relate: wii, controller, movements, electronic component -> accelerometer
relate: cell, division -> mitosis, meiosis, dna, histology, etc
relate: pokemon, red, not game, not version -> charmander, charizard, moltres, etc
```

Possibly showing relation rates in %, using similar methods to those used on Watson?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml), [VeryRelated](http://veryrelated.com/related.php?base=Python) or [WordNik](http://developer.wordnik.com/docs#!/word/get_related)

Comment: OneLook seems closer.